# The Forsaken and Balefire

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light, forsaken

From [Wikia](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Balefire):

> During the War of the Shadow, the use of balefire had a horrible effect on the pattern. Whole cities were burned out of existence and the pattern was almost destroyed before both sides decided not to use it anymore.

Considering the fact that the Dark One prefers chaos, why would he (or his) care for the effects of balefire? Once resurrected, the Forsaken are quite free with its (albeit limited) use. Moreover,

> In the last battle, Demandred and Mazrim Taim go nuts with its use amplified by the sceptre sa'angreal.

Something does not appear to compute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the reason is that the Forsaken and the Dark One don't share the same goals.  Most of the Forsaken want power or immortality, but the Dark One really wants the Pattern to be destroyed.  The only Forsaken who is really on board with this goal is Ishamael/Moridin.

RJ hints at this [here](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Source%3aTor_Questions_of_the_Week,_17_August_2004_-_25_January_2005).

In the War of Power, the Forsaken decided to stop using balefire because they don't want to destroy the world.  In the Prologue of Lord of Chaos, the Dark One specifically asks Demandred to use balefire in his service, and he is afraid for this reason.